# restricting filesystem rights to apache/php for anything but logging operations

Tags: php, apache, unix, permissions

Hello and merry Christmas,

I've got a wonder. My need is to allow the creation of custom log files and folders through php, however I don't want the php script to be able to execute any unlink or harmful operation on my unix server.

It is important to know that the users may use custom php script that's why I have to prevent at maximum harmful operations, BUT the one of creating log files.

Do you know whether this could be accomplished with Apache 2 under centOs6?

Thank you for your support,
S.

Comment: Can you do your logging through syslog? If so then you need grant no file writing permissions at all to the code.

Comment: thanks, I ignored this feature. I don't think it will match my needs but I'm going to have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use php's [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) setting to restrict them to a dedicated directory to create and modify log files in. In addition, you would want to configure apache to not serve/execute any files in that directory, because they may write executable files.

You still need to worry about disabling other functions like exec() to prevent them from running system commands, because open_basedir is a purely php enforced concept which doesn't affect the rest of the server via the filesystem permission system.

the "or harmful operation on my unix server" is the hard part. You might want to consider setting up a VM to give them a robust jailed environment.

Comment: that's funny because since I didn't have an answer, I researched more and more (and more... :D) and i reached the same conclusion. It costed me a little bit to adjust the architecture but now I've got a neat open_basedir + disable_functions .htaccess / php.ini setup. Thanks!

Comment: And by the way, thanks for the no execute trick, I didn't think about it :-)